# Loading a file form sftp location into salesforce

Tags: api, apex-webservice

I am working on a scenario where the file needs to be picked up from a SFTP server and loaded into salesforce.

Can salesforce web service pick up a file from sftp location and load it into salesforce? Whats the sytax for contructing a SFTP request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SFTP is not a protocol that Apex supports. If the external service cannot serve up the content by HTTP(S) you'll need something in the middle to mediate the file transfer.